# PowerShell: unwanted error if string is not found

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I am having an issue with a script that is supposed to print out the output if the expiry-epoch of a certificate is within 30 days of the present date.  However I found out that if the expiry-epoch string is now found then I get an error message "Cannot index into array" which messes up my output.

Please let me know how I can run this script on only files containing the expiry-epoch string

```
$c = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
$epochroundedtimes = [math]::Round($c)
$epochtimes = $epochroundedtimes + 2592000
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\scripts\PALO" -File -Recurse | 
  ForEach-Object { $epochtimes } {
    $certexp = 
      [double] ($_ | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch (\d+)$").Matches.Groups[1].Value
    if ($certexp -le $epochtimes) {
      $_.FullName
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$c = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
$epochroundedtimes=[math]::Round($c)
$epochtimes=$epochroundedtimes + 2592000

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\scripts\PALO" -File -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $epochMatch = $_ | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch (\d+)$"

        if($epochMatch)
        {
            $certexp = ([double]($epochMatch.Matches.Groups[1].Value))

            if($certexp -le $epochtimes)
            {
                $_.FullName
            }
        }
}
```

**EDIT: Adding a brief explanation, as per comments**

The error was being generated by this line in the original code sample:

```
$certexp = 
      [double] ($_ | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch (\d+)$").Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

This was problematic because if the target file does not contain the expected string, `Select-String` produces no output, so there is no `Matches` or `Group` properties to interrogate. Splitting this line into multiple steps made it possible to check that we had an object to work with before trying to access its properties.  That is, we attempt the string match:

```
$epochMatch = $_ | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch (\d+)$"
```

Then check `$epochMatch` is an actual object:

```
if($epochMatch)
```

If so, we then retrieve the matched value:

```
$certexp = ([double]($epochMatch.Matches.Groups[1].Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

[boxdog's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49804838/45375) explains the problem well and offers an effective solution.

Let me complement with a streamlined, more PowerShell-idiomatic solution that is more efficient while avoiding the original problem:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\scripts\PALO" -File -Recurse | 
  Select-String -Pattern "expiry-epoch (\d+)$" | 
    ForEach-Object {
      # Extract the capture-group value from the [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] 
      # instance that Select-String output.
      $certexp = [double] $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
      if ($certexp -le $epochtimes) {
        # The .Path property of the [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] 
        # instance contains the input file's full filename.
        $_.Path
      }
    }
```

Directly piping `Get-ChildItem`'s output to `Select-String` means that only matches are passed through the pipeline, on which the `ForEach-Object` call can then safely act.